# oauth implementation for authorization not working

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to create a dummy application that act as a server. Now I am integrating a dummy app inside my server app that act as a third party application.

I want to authenticate my third party app from server app for the user to access the services of server app and third party app.

I am working with nodejs and found oauth2 package but I am not able to do any thing properly.

Can you help me?

Comment: Check https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server?

Comment: i am not able to get any proper things from there